# Issue with How to create a signable HTML document in Docusign API (Node js)

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I tried to create a signable HTML document following the documentation https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/creating-signable-html/

But when I run the project the app crashed and show me a giant json where the only error code that i can see is: "errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'documents[0].htmlDefinition.source', line 1, position 123."

here is the code:

```
const docusign = require("docusign-esign");
const fs = require("fs");
```

```
let envelope = await makeEnvelopeHtml(name, email);

let results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope( accountId, {envelopeDefinition: envelope});
```

```
async function makeEnvelopeHtml(name, email){
   
   let signer = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
      email: email,
      name: name,
      recipientId: "1",
      routingOrder: "1",
      roleName: "Signer",
      });


   let recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    signers: [signer]
   });


   let html = 'template.html';

   let htmlDefinition = new docusign.DocumentHtmlDefinition();
   htmlDefinition.source = getHTMLDocument(html, name, email);

   let document = new docusign.Document();
   document.name="doc1.html";
   document.documentId="1";
   document.htmlDefinition=htmlDefinition;

   let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
   env.emailSubject = "Signing Document with HTML";
   env.documents = [document];
   env.recipients = recipients;
   env.status = "sent";
    
   return env;

}
```

```
async function getHTMLDocument(html, name, email){
   let docHTMLContent = fs.readFileSync(html, {encoding: "utf8"});
   let  content = docHTMLContent
   .replace("{signerName}", name)
   .replace("{signerEmail}", email)
   .replace("/sn1/", "<ds-signature data-ds-role=\"Signer\"/>")
   .replace("/sn1/", "<input data-ds-type=\"number\"/>")
   .replace("/l2q/", "<input data-ds-type=\"number\"/>");

   return content;
}
```

this is the content of template.html:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>{signerName} {signerEmail} /sn1/ /l1q/ /l2q/ </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `{signerName} {signerEmail}` inside your HTML `<body>` tag. These values should have been replaced when you created your document.
If you used the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) and it worked with the HTML file that's in there, that's a good starting point. Use [this file](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/demo_documents/order_form.html) as a baseline and change it as needed.